# How to convert a column in an inventory table into a map with graduated colors for polygons

Tags: arcmap

[image]I am new to GIS, so I am sure I will use some of the wrong terms. I have joined a CSV file to the attribute table of a vector shapefile with polygons (basically all watersheds on earth), using an ID common to both watershed polygons (original vector shapefile) and to the new data linked to watersheds (reliance on blue water, for 92 crops).

So I have 92 columns in the attribute table (plus column for the ID), one for each crop, and in each column I have a single unique data value for each of the watersheds. I would then like to represent the reliance on blue water, by each crop and watershed, with a graduated color ramp. In the end, I would like to have 92 separate shapefile maps, in my ArcMap document.

Somebody gave the advice to click on properties of the shapefile, then symbology, then quantities, then in the value field drop-down list choose the crop - but when I do that, the drop-down list only offers the watershed ID number (despite the data having been joined in the attribute table). I cannot choose categories: unique values, even though the crops show in the drop-down list, because there are hundreds of unique values, one for each watershed.

Any input?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing a sample of the attribute table?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model here, and you haven't really structured a question that can be answered in that model. While it would be possible to script the creation of 92 map *layers*, only one map is possible in a single ArcMap document at a time (the layers which are toggled *on* and are not disabled by scale dependency).

Comment: Thanks for your input Vince, I will take the tour. @BERA I have attached a screenshot. I somewhat solved the problem by replacing blank cells with a zero value in the original joined csv file. The crops then appeared in the dropdown list. Playing around, it seems as though there can be some NULL values in the joined table, but not too many. It is not ideal, because those NULL values / blank cells are supposed to represent no data, and the zero value mean no blue water use in a watershed. While clunky, it will do. It would be nice to join a single crop column to each of the 92 copied layers.